# How does PLSQL function return text validation work?

Tags: sql, oracle

Unfortunately my validation doesn't work when i click a submit button. When I do click the submit button 'what' appears as error which is b = null below. How would you validate a registration page after the person presses the submit button. Or how would you do validation after submit button?

```
DECLARE
    error_message varchar2(4000);
    b varchar2(500); 
    FUNCTION validate_field RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
        BEGIN
    b := :P101_REG_FIRST_NAME;
            IF (REGEXP_LIKE(b, '[A-Za-z]') AND :P101_NEW <> NULL AND NOT(REGEXP_LIKE(b, '[:space:]'))) THEN
                RETURN 'works' || b;

            ELSIF b IS NULL THEN
                RETURN b || 'what';

            ELSIF REGEXP_COUNT(b, '[A-Za-z]')  = 1 THEN 
                RETURN 'Name cannot be single letter';

                ELSE RETURN 'HUH' || ' ' || b;
            END IF;
        END;


        BEGIN
            error_message := '';
            error_message := validate_field;

            IF error_message IS NULL THEN
                RETURN NULL;
            ELSE
                RETURN error_message;
            END IF;
        COMMIT;
        END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I'll post the answer in the morning, it's late and I've stayed up too long solving this issue. I feel good though. Thank you for reading all of this.

Comment: **No need to post anything in the morning.** Most people know that a comparison like `'anything' <> NULL` is **never** true (this is very basic SQL stuff), and those who don't can reference probably hundreds of similar questions right here on Stack Overflow. The best thing for you to do, if you are satisfied with your own answer, is to **delete** your question entirely. Let's keep the site clean!